# Are there tutorials or simplified examples for how to use OpenGL texture blur?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, opengl-es, blur

I have a UIKit app (no OpenGL included yet) and I need to blur an image in there. Some people suggested to go with OpenGL texture blur for this. There's an sample project from Apple called "GLImageProcessing" but it's such a huge source base and filled with just too much of different stuff.

Maybe someone knows another source that showcases the texture blur on it's own, making it simple to follow the process how to set up an EAGLView that just does that one thing?

Comment: Are you looking for OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0?  The latter may give you greater control over your blurring effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to apply a Gaussian blur effect.  Here's a library somebody has provided to do this on a UIImage:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/